# Switch from one html tag to another using Xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

This is my HTML code:

```
<pre>
<span class="cm-string">"userId"</span>
":"
<span class="cm-string">"abc"</span>
","
</pre>
```

I need to capture the text "abc" from the "userId" tag as the value abc keeps changing instantly.

I tried with following code and it failed.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'userId')]/span")).getText();
```

Comment: Your question does not make sense. There is no `userId` tag. "userId" is itself the text content of a `span` element. Also, your java code makes no sense because you select a `span` that contains a certain string and then... return this string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `span` containing `abc` is a following sibling to the `span` containing `UserId`, use it:

```
//span[contains(., 'userId')]/following-sibling::span
```

Comment: One other doubt, there are many sub string with the name "userId" how do i locate the exact string "userId" ? Below code gives error due to cotes //span[contains(., '"userId"')]/following-sibling::span

Comment: @user3174553 sure, just escape quotes and don't use `contains()`:`//span[. = '\"userId\"']/following-sibling::span`

Comment: <pre>
<span class="cm-string">"userId"</span>
":"
<span class="cm-string">"abc"</span>
","
</pre><pre>
<span class="cm-string">"password"</span>
":"
<span class="cm-string">"xyz"</span>                       
","
</pre> in this above code how do i access from abc to xyz. i will be really thankful if you help me with this last code.